# RegExp for stripping URLs from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to take a Twitter text like this:

```
s = "Today 09/07 sunday http://t.co/123 - AC/DC COVER Opening and DVD - woman R$10 / man R$15. - http://migre.me/59qwc"
```

and turn it into this..

```
s = "Today 09/07 sunday LINK - AC/DC COVER Opening and DVD - woman R$10 / man R$15. - LINK"
```

This snippet is failing for some reason, please, some help

```
s.replace(/(http\:.*)\s/g , 'LINK')
```

Comment: I would assume its not replacing anything...

Comment: I would expect that it replaces everything from "sunday " to "http://migre.me/59qwc" with LINK :)

Comment: It's not matching `http://migre.me/59qwc` because there is no space after it.

Comment: @mike: Yeah, the stackoverflow interpreter ate my http bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
/\bhttps?\:\S*/ig
```

which uses `\S*` to match runs of non-space characters so won't have problems matching at the end of input where there is no following space.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
input.replace(/http:\/{2}[^\s]+/,"link")
```

Answer (score 0):

.* will eat all, including whitespace, so this finds everything, until it cannot go further, then it backtracks to find the single whitespace character. You'll have to match only non-whitespace characters for the URL and you will be done.

Comment: Don't forget that the URL does *not* have to end with a whitespace though, in Java I would have used reluctant quantifiers to achieve this, including a end of input ($), but the JavaScript language seems to be less capable.

Comment: @owistead, `$` works just fine in JavaScript.  In general though, you're right.  The JavaScript regular expression language is missing a few things that `java.util.regex` has including lookbehind and unicode character classes.

Comment: @mike: I wasn't saying that $ was missing from JavaScript (that would have been weird), but that I would have included $ in the part with the reluctant quantifiers - and those *are* missing. Of course, that does not withhold smart guys like you to give an answer without them :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated, `.*` will match whitespace and thus replace everything. Depending on the system you are using, you may be able to get away with something like `\S*`, which matches only non-whitespace characters, or else a more explicit [^ ]* instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should strip HTML from your text

```
s.replace(/<.*?>/g, '');
```

Comment: That's a nice regex for removing _tags_, but the original question was asking about removing urls that begin with "http://" or "https://".